# UWP Navigation View Selection Indicator

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have an UWP application with a customn style for the selection indicator:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"
                 Color="{StaticResource FoxOrange}" />
```

[image]

Now I wanted to switch to the Version in the Microsoft.UI.Xaml package. That works so far, unless that the sselection indicator is no longer orange but in the default accent color again and much smaller.

[image]

How can I adjust that back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the color. You still can define this in your page like this:

```
 <Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground" Color="Yellow"/>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

But I cannot find a way to customize the width of this SelectionIndicator, as far as I konw, it's a rectangle defined in NavigationViewItemPresenter.

Comment: I tried adding my Style to a project generated with the App Studio and that worked as expected. So I assume that there is somethingwrong with my project. I just can't figure out what..

Comment: I just found it out.. Version 2.0.181018004 seems to work as expected. However with version 2.1.190405004 the behaviour above occurs..

Comment: Alright, I did some further investigation. It seems there was a width change in the latest version (2.1.190405004), which is a bit confusing for me ^^ Also I had my Style in a own ResourceDictionary which was loaded. That didn't work anymore when I switched to the Library instead of using the built in. When I moved the style over to the Page.Resource it worked. Thanks!